# how to cast a const base class pointer into the derived class

Tags: c++

I am trying to cast a base class pointer into the derived class object. I can cast using old style but not with new style. I found some similar questions but don't find the answer.

Below is a downsized example of my problem. 
This line `((Scalar<int>*)base)->get();` gives me the correct result.
This line `static_cast<Scalar<int>*>(base)->get();` results in compiler error: error: static_cast from type 'const Base*' to type 'Scalar*' casts away qualifiers

```
class Base
{
    public:
    Base() {};
    virtual ~Base() {};
    int getID() const { return 1; };
};


template<class T> class Scalar : public Base
{
    public:
        Scalar() {};
        ~Scalar() {};
        void set(const T value)
        {
            m_value = value;
        }
        T get() const { return m_value; }
    private:
        T m_value;
};


class Access
{
public:
    const Base *find() const
    {
        return &m_scalar;
    }

    void example()
    {
        m_scalar.set(25);

        const Base *base = find();

        int res1 = ((Scalar<int>*)base)->get();
        int res2 = static_cast<Scalar<int>*>(base)->get();


        std::cout << res1 << std::endl;
        std::cout << res2 << std::endl;

    }
private:
    Scalar<int> m_scalar;
};
```

Comment: Casting away `const` is in 99.999% of all cases a really bad idea. And because of that you need to use a special construct: [`const_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast). And as a general tip: If you ever feel the need to use a C-style cast, then you're most likely doing something wrong.

Comment: With that out of the way, why don't you cast to a `const` pointer? As in `const Scalar<int>*`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do

```
int res1 = ((Scalar<int>*)base)->get();
```

you do what is called a c-style cast.  This works because c-style casts don't do any checking and ignore the casting away of `const`.  They just cast the source type to the destination regardless of any consequences.

On the other hand `static_cast` actually checks what you are doing and sees you are trying to cast the constness of `base` away.  That isn't allowed by any cast except `const_cast` so you get an error.  We could use that here to get rid of the constness but that isn't needed.  What you can do is just cast to a `const Scalar<int>*` using

```
int res2 = static_cast<const Scalar<int>*>(base)->get();
```

Comment: Yes this works in my example, but I am wondering by myself because using this solution in my original project I get this error error: passing 'const xxxx<int>' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]. There must be a difference between the example and the real world.

Comment: @Inok Sounds like the function you are trying to call is not marked `const` unlike how `get` is in your example.  That would cause that error.  If that is the case you either need to make that function `const` (preferred) or cast away constness (not preferred).  The problem you get with casting away constness is if the object is truly `const`, then modifying it will be undefined behavior.

Comment: You are absolutely right. In my real project I call set not get. Using this in my example I get the same error. But I can't use const in the setter. What would be the right solution?

Comment: @Inok To me the right solution would be to get `base` as a non-const pointer in the first place.  Like in your example instead through `find`, just use `m_scalar` directly.  If you can't then see if it is possible to get the pointer in a non const version.  If you can't do that then you might have to cast away const but I strogly recommend you don't.  What you can do is post a new question with a [mcve] that exactly mimics what you are really trying to do and ask if there is a way to get the pointer without it being const.  This may sound dramatic but `const_cast` is very dangerous.

Comment: Yea, the point is find() is not so simple I described it, but I will think if I find a way. Thank you!

Comment: @Inok No problem.  I am going to roll back your edit to the question though since it invalidates all of the answers.  If you want to talk about the new example you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 4):

You missed `const`:

```
static_cast<Scalar<int> const*>(base)->get();
```

I would strongly suggest avoiding using C-style casts in C++ code because the exact semantics of the cast may change silently when the argument types change. [See what C-style cast does](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast).

Answer (score 4):

The compiler error pretty much nails it down, you can't cast away the `const`-ness of what is returned from `get()` with a `static_cast`. Hence:

```
static_cast<const Scalar<int> *>(base)->get();
```

Remember that casting away `const` often is a code smell, see also [ES.50](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es50-dont-cast-away-const).